# How to change the project used by Indexer during a Vim session?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to use Indexer ([vimscript #3221](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3221)) to index the files of a specific project created with project.vim ([vimscript #69](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69)). As the plugin's documentation says, if I don't set the `g:indexer_projectsSettngsFilename` variable in ~/.vimrc, it uses ~/.vimprojects file by default. But I want to be able to specify the project without setting that variable in ~/.vimrc (i.e., I want to do it in a more local way).

I tried to set `g:indexer_projectsSettngsFilename` in [_vimrc_local.vim](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc), setting it manually after Vim is started, re-source the plugin (by running `:so`) once the variable has been set, run `:IndexerRebuild` afterwards. In either case the plugin does not create the index file for the project.

So how can I make Indexer to change its project during a Vim session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Indexer plugin has a dependency: [Vimprj](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3872), which manages options for different projects: exactly what you need.

The [Indexer repository](https://bitbucket.org/dfrank/vim-indexer) has some examples under `doc/examples` directory. Check, for example, [`doc/examples/vimprj_indexer_files`](https://bitbucket.org/dfrank/vim-indexer/src/b052d21a5fee574a7a0f1648168cbe55d51f9e8f/doc/examples/vimprj_indexer_files/?at=default).

In short, in the root directory of your project, you need to create the `.vimprj` directory, and after this, when you open some file under your project directory, all `.vimprj/*.vim` files will be sourced, and `$INDEXER_PROJECT_ROOT` variable will be set to the path of your project (which is one level above the `.vimprj` dir).

I usually put my `.indexer_files` in `.vimprj` directory too, and refer to it from `.vimprj/my.vim` file like this:

```
" get path to ".vimprj" folder
let s:sPath = expand('<sfile>:p:h')

" specify our ".vimprj/.indexer_files"
let g:indexer_indexerListFilename = s:sPath.'/.indexer_files'
```

And I can refer from `.indexer_files` to `$INDEXER_PROJECT_ROOT` like this:

```
[my_project]
option:ctags_params = "--langmap=c:.c.h --languages=c"

$INDEXER_PROJECT_ROOT
```

For more information, see the article: [Vim: convenient code navigation for your projects](http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation), which explains the usage of Indexer + Vimprj thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't consider using .indexer_files because I was using the project.vim plugin. I was thinking in a way like setting some option in a .vimprj file to change the Indexer project and reload it (by re-sourcing or executing a command). I think it would be much simpler, but this solution works fine.